# What book is this where a smuggler wakes up to A.I. in his head?

Tags: story-identification, space, artificial-intelligence

The book i am trying to remember is that this person in space, (who I think is a smuggler?), hyperdrives to another star, but along the way he passes out and wakes up to an A.I. in his head.

This A.I. near the end of the book "possible spoilers" takes a container along with herself and goes off the ship while they are flying at hyper speed, making sure it doesn't fall into the wrong hands and saving other A.I.?

Along the way, the a.i. turns into a person, more or less a girl, and they have to find a way to get the a.i. container back from a organization, planing on having other AI used as weapons against there enemy's.

Comment: Is there a super power (possibly called the interstellar--) which has special hyper drives, while everyone else mashes do with a much slower drive +  suspended animation? And is this smuggler one of several people (most ate dead) discovered the hyperdrives, and then head then stolen from him?